# Excel sum of cells with IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Let's say I have this condition:

```
  | Col A        | Col B    
10 |Jan 1 2017   | €15.0    
11 |Jan 2 2017   | €17.0    
12 |Jan 3 2017   | €11.0    
...| ...         | ...    
186|June 26 2017 | € 23.55
```

In cell B1 I would like the sum of the money from a certain date to another
So, let's say, I would like to know the sum during April. What I know about the IF statement is something like this IF($A:SA<=;true;false) but this will give me 0 because it will refear to A1 instead of all column A.
I don't know if I was clear enough but, if someone got it, could give me some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Dates are true dates then Use SUMIFS() and braket the dates:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=" & DATE(2017,4,1),A:A,"<" & Date(2017,5,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B*(MONTH(A:A)=4))
```